# c#: serial data write from read thread

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am sending and receiving data from a device using
c# (serial communication). **For receiving** my setup is like this. 
I am receiving on a separate thread i.e. I have something like this

```
comPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(comPort_DataReceived);

private void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    .....
}
```

**To write** I push a button which write data to the device.

Now I was thinking to write data automatically when ever I receive some data from device instead of me pushing
the button when ever I receive data. So my q is that can I put 
`comPort.WriteLine(textBox1.Text + "\r\n");` in the body of

```
private void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
```

function. Becase when I put write here it stops working. Otherwise write works with separate button push as I mentioned above.

Can somebody tell me whats the correct way. Is there any issue of threads or someting

Thanks !

Comment: Accessing `textBox1.Text` from a thread that is not the main/UI thread is the cause of your problem...

Comment: But how can I use input of text book in the read thread ? I mean this code comPort.WriteLine(textBox1.Text + "\r\n");

Comment: Not knowing the details of your protocol, I'll throw this out there: receiving on a separate thread is usually only necessary if your peripheral can send data at any given time. If the protocol is host-initiated (ie. The PC causes all transactions to begin) then the separate thread just com RX is probably unnecessary. One background thread using blocking TX & RX is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Any operation with UI controls (including reading and writing properties like `Text`) should be done in application's main thread. If you are in another thread, you should use the [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) method to do the operation:

```
var text = (string)textBox1.Invoke(new Func<string>(() =>
    {
        return textBox1.Text;
    }));
comPort.WriteLine(text + "\r\n");
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1423500/1174942) answer for more information.