# Can't Close form from event

Tags: c#, invoke

My main Form, named Form1 has a class with an event which indicates that Form1 should be Closed.

When I receive the event and try to `Close` I get the excepcion that a control.invoke must be used. Fine, I make the call with this code and I'm still getting the same exception:

```
void Prox_OkEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        callControlhandler c = new callControlhandler(CloseForm);
        c.Invoke();
    }
    else Close();
}

private void CloseForm()
{
    try { this.Close(); }
    catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); }
}
```

Where is the problem? thanks for any help

Comment: Is this call comes from a different thread? Can you post the exact error?

Comment: Also try to read Jon Skeet answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423446/thread-control-invoke

Comment: Is `CerrarForm` meant by `CloseForm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Invoke` should be called against the `Form` itself.  In this case it is called against `c`.

Try...

```
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(CerrarForm));
        }
```

Comment: +1 The point of `Invoke` is to pass it to the GUI thread. OP's code is simply invoking the delegate on the current thread.