# Control.Invoke must be used to interact with controls created on a separate thread

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

Below is the method to start a thread in compact framework 3.5

```
public ScanEntry(string scanId)
{
   InitializeComponent();
    _scanId = scanId;
    //reader = deviceFactory.Create();
    //reader.YMEvent += new ScanEventHandler(reader_Reading);
    //reader.Enable();
 }


private void CasesEntry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      caseCounterLabel.Text = cases.Count.ToString();
      scanIdValueLabel.Text = _scanId;
}



internal void menuItemNewScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       System.Threading.ThreadStart threadDelegate = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ScanEvents);
       System.Threading.Thread newThread = new System.Threading.Thread(threadDelegate);
       newThread.Start();
}
```

which calls the below method on thread

```
private void ScanEvents()
{

  try
  {

     //some other codes     
      if (scanIdValueLabel.InvokeRequired)
     {
          scanIdValueLabel.Invoke((Action)(() => scanIdValueLabel.Text = "value"));
      }  


     attributeNode = docEventFile.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Attribute", string.Empty);
     XMLUtils.CreateAttribute(docEventFile, attributeNode, "name", "SCANID");
     XMLUtils.CreateAttribute(docEventFile, attributeNode, "value", scanIdValueLabel.Text);
     attributeSetNode.AppendChild(attributeNode);
     //some other codes
  }
  catch(Execption e)
  {
     Message.Show(e.Message);
  }
}
```

**Errors:**

```
TextAlign = 'scanIdValueLabel.TextAlign' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' 
base {System.SystemException} = {"Control.Invoke must be used to interact with controls created on a separate thread."}
```

**In Line**

```
XMLUtils.CreateAttribute(docEventFile, attributeNode, "value", scanIdValueLabel.Text);
```

I am getting `Control.Invoke must be used to interact with controls created on a separate thread` at this line

```
XMLUtils.CreateAttribute(docEventFile, attributeNode, "value", scanIdValueLabel.Text);
```

I have googled and tried with that solutions but not worked for me.Can any one help me in doing this.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot access the `scanIdValueLabel.Text` from another thread.

Comment: What is behind Message.Show, is this one interacting with the controls on your form?

Comment: @S.Spieker Can you explain me some what clear.

Comment: @Complexity Message.Show i just placed for debug to know the exact error.But i tried without that and not worked.

Comment: It's a general rule that you should and cannot access forms properties from another thread than the thread creating the controls...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread Control.Invoke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423446/thread-control-invoke)

Comment: @Complexity Ok,Can you tell me in my case how to handle a thread

Comment: See my answer below. Does that help you in achieving what you want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Way to Invoke Any Cross-Threaded Code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711408/best-way-to-invoke-any-cross-threaded-code)

Comment: @S.Spieker You can access the Text property, or any other property of a UI control from a background thread, as long as you don't try to modify it. Only when you write to it, invoking on Dispatcher thread is required.

Comment: @Royal Can you show us what is happening in XMLUtils.CreateAttribute?

Comment: According to some comments om what I have replied, when you're on you're seperate thread, do you try to modify any of your controls?

Comment: @Complexity I am not modify any controls,however i am processing the values of controls in ScanEvents method.

Answer (score 9):

When you're dealing with Winforms, WPF, Silverlight there's the following sentence which is very important:

The UI elements can only be accessed by the UI thread. WinForms, WPF, Silverlight doesn't allow access to controls from multiple threads.

However, there is a solution which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711408/best-way-to-invoke-any-cross-threaded-code):

**Update: I've created a sample application to make some things clear:**

[image]

I've created a form first with a button and a label on it. The label is not visible because it doesn't contain text, but it's right underneath the button.

*Scenario 1: Updating without threads:*

```
private void btnStartThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Button has been clicked.";
}
```

Off course this is not a problem. It's some standard code:

*Scenario 2: Updating with threads:*

```
private void btnStartThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.ThreadStart threadDelegate = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ScanEvents);
    System.Threading.Thread newThread = new System.Threading.Thread(threadDelegate);
    newThread.Start();
}

private void ScanEvents()
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Exected in another thread.";
}
```

This will fail because I'm MODIFYING the controls on my form from another thread:

[image]

Now, I will modify the code so that I'm changing the label with an action through an invoke on the label.

```
private void ScanEvents()
{
    if (lblMessage.InvokeRequired)
    {
        lblMessage.Invoke((Action)(() => lblMessage.Text = "This text was placed from within a thread."));
    }
}
```

This will make the text change.

[image]

So, I hope that it helps. If not, please shout :-)

Comment: If you believe this is a duplicate you should flag it as such rather than simply linking to an existing question.

Comment: Done. Sorry but I didn't knew it.

Comment: @Complexity You can access UI elements from a background thread as long as you don't attempt to modify any of their properties. READ ONLY is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but looking at the original question, it's not clear if one of the properties is modified.

Comment: @Complexity can you tell me how to use InvokeRequired in my application.Since the code what i given in question is for creating xml attributes and i added the InvokeRequired above the 4 line in question in ScanEvents method.Still i am getting the same exception what you mentioned in answer.Do i want to add the InvokeRequired to the place where i am passing the input to textbox control.Please clarify

Comment: Can you update your question with what you have right now, that will make things easier. Also place the code where you're padding the input to the textbox control. Then I'll probably be able to help you out.

Comment: @Complexity I edited the question with updates.Please help me to do theading.

Comment: And where do you have the error because I don't see it?

Comment: I am not able to take screen shot of error,but i updated the error and line in question.Please see Errors and In line in question.

Comment: Let's move to the chat, so avoid a very long post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56947/discussion-between-complexity-and-royal).

Comment: The value of scanIdValueLabel is not changed until a submit is completed.Without using thread i debugged and noticed that a 6 digit number(ranchid) is passing to that.What could be the cause on using thread.

Comment: Well, you're saying that the value is changed when a submit is completed. From which thread is the submit called? If it's not from the UI thread, you will need InvokeRequired, try adding an InvokeRequired for changing the TextAlign property.